# Returning data objects from ajax query to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm attempting to access data from a form and pass it to a controller in MVC.

I was successful in passing the data when I get the element by ID and pass as string:

This works:

```
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
         'Answer0': $("#Answer0").val(), 
         'Answer1': $("#Answer1").val(), 
         'Question0': $("#Question0").val() 
    }),
```

However I want to bring the data in as a viewmodel.  When I specify the request as:

```
    data: JSON.stringify($('#' + formDiv).serializeObject()),
```

It will populate the viewmodel, however there are fields that are not bound to the ViewModel that I would like to pass along with the serialized form.  I have tried just adding them, but they don't seem to come in if I pass both the serialized form object and the additional string.

```
    function clickedNext(e, formDiv) {
    var sURL = '@Url.Action("SurveySave", "Home")'
    $.ajax({
        url: sURL,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify($('#' + formDiv).serializeObject(), { 'Answer0': $("#Answer0").val(), 'Answer1': $("#Answer1").val() }),
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#InvestigationStatus').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SurveySave(SurveyViewModel s, string Answer0, string Answer1)
```

Comment: What are the down votes for?

Comment: Show your model and view. First you using a view model so having additional parameters in your POST method makes no sense. Second, if you view is generated correctly then all you need is `data: $('form').serialize(),` to correctly serialize your data (and `.serializeObject()` is not even part of jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you can't put two objects inside of `JSON.stringify();`

Maybe try something like:

```
var bothObjects = {
    $('#' + formDiv).serializeObject(),
    { 'Answer0': $("#Answer0").val(), 'Answer1': $("#Answer1").val() }
}
...

    JSON.stringify(bothObjects),
```